# Can Resque be used to enqueue jobs to multiple redis databases on different servers?

Tags: redis, resque

For instance... From the same rails app I would like to be able to queue email to one redis db at "localhost:6379" and imports to another redis db at "10.0.0.5:6379".

This seems to set the redis connection app wide.
Resque.redis = "localhost:6379"

Is there a way to instantiate and use multiple redis connections with Resque?

Answer (score 3):

This project does what im looking for!

https://github.com/redsquirrel/resque_redis_composite